# Add "key" attribute to a component that is saved within a variable

Tags: reactjs

In my application i need to load multiple menus depending on what product user has installed. This is what I'm doing:

```
renderProductMenus() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                {this.state.loadedProducts.map(loadedProduct => loadedProduct.state.productMenu)}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

productMenu in this instance is a component. But i'm getting a warning

> "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop."

the easiest way for me was to add "key" property directly to a component like this:

```
<ProductMenu key="mykey" />
```

but i was looking to se if this can be done during the loading stage, somehow like this:

```
loadedProduct => loadedProduct.state.productMenu.addProp({key: value})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You can add a React.Fragment wrapper around your component and add the key to that. An example is provided below:

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        loadedProducts: [ 
        <ProductMenu name = 'Menu1' / >, 
        <ProductMenu name = 'Menu2' / >,
        <ProductMenu name = 'Menu3' / >
        ]
      };
    }

    render() {
      const menuItems = this.state.loadedProducts.map((menu, i) => {
        return (
        <React.Fragment key={i}>
        {menu} 
        </React.Fragment>);
      });
      return (<div>{menuItems}</div>);
      }
    }

    class ProductMenu extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <div>{this.props.name}</div>
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render( <Main /> ,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root" />
```

**Method 2:**

You can use `React.cloneElement` instead of adding additional wrapper.

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        loadedProducts: [ 
        <ProductMenu name = 'Menu 1' / >, 
        <ProductMenu name = 'Menu 2' / >,
        <ProductMenu name = 'Menu 3' / >
        ]
      };
    }

    render() {
      const menuItems = 
      React.Children.map(this.state.loadedProducts, (menu,  i) =>
          React.cloneElement(menu, { key:  i })
      );
      return (<div>{menuItems}</div>);
      }
    }

    class ProductMenu extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <div>{this.props.name}</div>
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render( <Main /> ,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This will definitely work, but i was looking for a more elegant solution that doesn't require writing lots of additional code

Comment: @AnKing Thanks. I added a second method to the answer. An alternative way is to use React.cloneElement.

Comment: How about React Hooks, so functional components?